# I have recorded a test plan for Files Upload processs from Blazemeter, still when I try to run it for the second time, get "Bad Request-->400" error

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, load, performance-testing, blazemeter

I did as follows:

1. recorded a test script regarding file upload using Blazemeter.
2. tried to upload another file, so I replaced a new file with the previous one inside the "Jmeter --> Bin" directory.
3. Before running the script just changed the filename "Parameter -->vale" like the screenshot:
   [image: image description]
4. When I run the scripts, it shows error:
   [image: image description]

Answer (score 1):

This request doesn't look like a proper one to me, my expectation is that the file should go to "Files Upload" folder of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and `Use multipart/form-data` box should be checked.

[image]

I would rather recommend re-recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just make sure to copy the file you're uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder before executing the file upload request in browser. More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: Hello, @Dmitri T ,I just tried another time with a new recording and followed the styeps that you said, still no help,  https://prnt.sc/uic07j   & https://prnt.sc/uic0ys

Comment: Hello, I figured it out, I used "Recording" template and now it's working fine. thanks much. I could be able to upload files in my system. :)